# For what queries is conditional tags informative?

Tags: wp-query, conditional-tags

I think it's great to use [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) but if the query is slightly advanced it won't give information about the original query. For example; is_category('apple') *might* give a false response if "banana" AND "apple" has been queried. This is because is_category() compares against one single category and doesn't bother about the rest.

I need a way to know when I can expect that conditional tags won't give complete information about the original query. Can someone explain the limits of wordpress conditional tags?

Comment: There's an answer to this question and the correct answer would be useful for the wp community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is_category('apple') might give a false response if "banana" AND "apple" has been queried

you're using `is_category` incorrectly in this context. From Codex:

> is_category();
>   // When any Category archive page is being displayed.

A category archive page is for a single term, if a query is a for more than one term, it's not a term archive page. so it's not a matter of "giving complete information" it's a matter of understanding what each tag actually indicates.

Comment: Yeah, I can't use is_category() in some situations and that's why I ask for a better understanding. Like many others I use conditional tags in actions and filters, not just in specific templates. I don't believe that's wrong.